# How i can adding shortcut keys for java code in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to add a quick shortcut like (`sout` + Tab = `System.out.println()` ) in eclipse how I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Window>Preferences>Java>Editor>Templates>New

edit name and pattern

try it

Answer (score 1):

There is already a shortcut for `System.out.println()`.

just type `sysout` then press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd>.

If you want to make a template for other code, for example `System.out.print()`, Go to Preferences > Java > Editor > Templates and create a new template. To use the newly created template, type the `name` of the template + <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd>.